# PHP preg_match and regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm new for PHP

I am trying to get topic number of link but not work.

`echo $topicsave` is empty.

This my code.

```
$data = '
<a href="http://forums.inwing.com/index.php/topic,40500.0.html">test_curl</a>
';
preg_match_all('/\<a[^\?]+\/([^\"]+)\.\s*\>test_curl\<\/a\>/', $data, $match);
    echo '<pre>',htmlspecialchars(print_r($match, true)),'</pre>';
    if( count($match[0])){
    foreach($match[1] as $vl){
        preg_match_all('/topic\,([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $vl, $m1);
        if(count($m1[1])) 

           $topicsave = $m1[1][0];
           echo $topicsave;

    }
}
```

I want to get topic number `40500` please help me, topic is variable such as 120 or `2536` or `12456`.

Thank you.

Comment: Your regex looks needlessly complicated. Why not just `\/topic\,(\d+)\.(\d+)\.html` ?

Comment: You said `40500` in question. But in your attempt you are also trying to match the number after `dot`. Which one is true ?

Comment: @apokryfos: The part `\.(\d+)` should be optional or many. Try `(\.\d+)*`. Because there could be number like `123.0.02`.

Comment: regex is not the tool to parse html, use `DOMDocument` that is designed for, and eventually `parse_url` to get the path.

Comment: Thank you all , but first i want to get $data with  preg_match_all fixed subject of topic "test_curl" like my code in line 4

Answer (score 1):

To extract the topic number from link you can use following regex.

**Regex:** `topic,(\d+(\.\d+)*)\.html`

**Explanation:** What am doing is **feeding** your link to regex and extracting number between `topic,` and `.html`.

### **<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS7oL1/1)</kbd>**

### **<kbd>[PHP demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/uA98Sw)</kbd>**

Comment: thank you so much It' work for topic number.  but first step I want to find the subject of topic such as "test_curl" to get link url like $data and second step to get topic number please help to get <a href="http://forums.inwing.com/index.php/topic,40500.0.html">test_curl</a> with preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this:

```
$re = "/topic,(?'topic'\\d+)/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"http://forums.inwing.com/index.php/topic,40500.0.html\">test_curl</a>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

echo $matches['topic'];
```

Which will output:

> 40500

What I used here `(?'topic'\\d+)` is a *named group*. It allows you to retrieve data from your matches with the name you used (here `topic`).

If you need to do live tests, [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is great.

Comment: Hey Thomas can you please suggest me reference links from where i can learn about regular expressions as i didn't understand it.

Comment: I think OP is confused about what type of number he wants to match. Because his attempt shows he wants to match `dot` too.

Comment: @RK12: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas and noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$data = '<a href="http://forums.inwing.com/index.php/topic,40500.0.html">test_curl</a>';
preg_match_all('/topic,(.*?)\..*\.html/s', $data, $match);    
echo $match[1][0]; // Output: 40500
```